# Choosing a $x \in$ $X$, with $X$ an infinte set, $<$ a well-ordering on $X$, such that $x < x'$ for only finitely many $x' \in X$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Let $X$ be an (countable or not) infinite  set, $<$ a well-ordering on this set.

Lately I read a proof in which was explicitly stated to choose an element $x \in X$ such that there are infinitely many $x' \in X$ satisfying $x<x'$. Clearly $x_0$ the minimal element of $X$, which exists because of the well-ordering, would do the job. But wouldn't any element of X do the job?

I cannot think of any example where $X$ is an infinite set and any x that does not satisfy this condition. Is there such an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if the well order has a maximal element, using it is a counterexample.

Comment: thanks so far. Could you give a more explicit example of an infite set X  and a well-ordering that satisfys this condition?

Comment: @cookieMaster $\omega+1$ with $x=\omega$

Comment: okay thanks than for $ x= \omega $  only $ \omega +1 $ would be greater

Comment: @CookieMaster actually no. $\omega+1$ is not in $\omega+1$. $\omega$ is the maximal element as Asaf suggested. This is also the minimal counterexample assuming AC. $\omega+1=\{0,1,2,3\cdots,\omega\}$

Comment: @DRF: What does the axiom of choice has to do with that? :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Well ... I was just hedging really. I suppose that if there was a smaller counter example it would still have to be well ordered and you could use the well ordering to find an injection by induction.